# Django-filters is it possible to skip values that aren't a choice in the filter?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I want to filter events by who hosts them in my API. NOTE: Hosts do not have their own tables. They are just a field on an event.

I want to be able to send multiple values and grab all their events. So for instance if I query like this api/events?host=ashley&host=bob, it will return both bob's and ashley's events.

But if a user enters in another name that doesn't have an event, I'd still like it to return the other hosts events.

Is that possible, to skip non existent choices?

I've been using the django-filter AllValuesMultipleFilter function to filter all the hosts. Is there a way to skip over a choice if it doesn't exist?

```py
class EventFilter(dr_filters.FilterSet):
    after_start_date = dr_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name="start_date", lookup_expr="gte")
    before_end_date = dr_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name="end_date", lookup_expr="lte")
    category = dr_filters.AllValuesFilter(field_name="categories__name")
    venue = dr_filters.AllValuesFilter(field_name="venue__name")
    status = dr_filters.AllValuesMultipleFilter(field_name="event_status")
    host = dr_filters.AllValuesMultipleFilter(field_name="host")

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = (
            "after_start_date",
            "before_end_date",
            "internal_only",
            "category",
            "venue",
            "status",
            "host"
        )

# Define ViewSets
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, dr_filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = EventFilter
    search_fields = ("name",)
    ordering_fields = ("name", "start_date", "venue",)

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Event.objects.filter(start_date__gte=timezone.now())
        qs = qs.order_by("start_date")

        return qs
```

```
{
    "host": [
        "Select a valid choice. emma is not one of the available choices."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a necro post but I was searching for solutions and found nothing. So for anyone still looking here a quick fix, giving three possibilities I think you need to tweak it for your own cases (or make a nice implementation that always works!)

In the end I ended up just re-implementing the AllValuesFilter a little bit (did it for the multiple but it is the same for both). This way it just gets the choices directly from what is possible:

```
class AllValuesMultipleFilterAllChoices(MultipleChoiceFilter):

@property
def field(self):
    qs = <INSERT MODEL OF CHOICES>.objects.all()
    self.extra["choices"] = [(o.id, o.id) for o in qs]
    return super().field   

class AllValuesFilterAllChoices(ChoiceFilter):

@property
def field(self):
    qs = <INSERT MODEL OF CHOICES>.objects.all()
    self.extra["choices"] = [(o.id, o.id) for o in qs]
    return super().field 

class AllValuesMultipleFilterAllAllowed(MultipleChoiceFilter):

@property
def field(self):
    print(self.field_name)
    if '__' in self.field_name:
        field_name, field_attribute = tuple(self.field_name.split('__'))
        field_model = self.model._meta.get_field(field_name)
        choices = field_model.related_model.objects.all().values_list(field_attribute, flat=True)
        self.extra['choices'] = [(choice, choice) for choice in choices]
    else:
        self.extra['choices'] = self.model._meta.get_field(self.field_name).get_choices()
    return super().field
```